# Possible ways to change flag values inside a while loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, flags

So my problem is this: I'm running a while loop that will execute Function1 every time, Function2 and Function3 will only be executed when their respective flags are set to True, and I want to be able to **alter those flags while the loop is running**.

```
while brkFlag == False:  
    Function1.run()
    if flag2 == True:
        Function2.run()
    else:
        pass    
    if flag3 == True:
        Function3.run()
    else:
        pass
    if someConditions == True:
        brkFlag = True
```

Currently I want to change those flags with a GUI while the loop is running and am trying to do this with tkinter's Buttons and Checkboxes, but no luck so far.

I also can't use multithreading or multiprocessing as they will considerably slow down the speed of the loop (which is already barely acceptable as it is right now, because there are lots of calculations in each function and I need to show the results in a real-time fashion).

Edit: So it seems that there is no way other than doing multithreading/processing after all.

Comment: Just a side note...You can actually remove the `else` snippet

Comment: Yeah, I know, since pass does not do anything. However I may add something in the future so I just leave it like that for now. It's like a format.

Comment: not sure about the gui aspect but could you set an **enabled** flag on the function object itself?  **Function2.enabled = True**. test that in the loop and set it in the gui?  also, i don’t know how you plan to “reach in” from the gui and change _any_ objects for the loop, unless the gui and the loop are *both running*, *in the same process*. which means threads.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to pass a mutable container containing the flags, for example a list:

```
flags = [flag2, flag3, someConditions ]
while brkFlag == False:  
    Function1.run(flags)
    if flags[0] == True:
        Function2.run(flags)
    else:
        pass    
    if flags[1] == True:
        Function3.run(flags)
    else:
        pass
    if someConditions == True:     # or if flags[2] == True:
        brkFlag = True
```

In the callee you implement more or less:

```
...
def run(flags):
    ...
    flags[0] = True    # set flag2
    ...
```

Comment: Uhm, then how can I change the values of that container when my while loop is running?

Comment: No man... I mean, is there a way to change those flags without using a separate thread/process to interrupt that while loop ? That loop actually take live image frames from a camera and process them, so I would really like to be able to alter those flags without interrupting the live video feed. I cannot use multithreading/processing because my program would be worthless if it becomes any slower than it already is.

Comment: @BaoTran: It looks that I have missed your point... Unfortunately, I'm afraid I cannot really understand where is your problem. Changing variables from a GUI in normally what a GUI is made for. The common use is one thread for the GUI and eventually one or more worker threads to keep the GUI responsive during long operations. The only constraint is that a background thread should never act on the GUI.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it seems there is no other way around using multithreads after all. I actually tried multithreading before but the frame rate of the camera would drop considerably. Not sure if I did something wrong or multithreading does really slow down python programs in general. Thank you for being patient with me.